# How to undo <Ctrl+G> in Object Mode? Green color selection

Tags: object-mode

I'm an absolute beginner in Blender. Now I've accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in *Object Mode*, the selection color turned into Green selection. How could I make it back to Yellow / Orange color please?

I've been through this Blender Hotkey Wiki:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_HotKeys/3D_View/Object_Mode and it says here:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> brings up menu for performing group operations on selected objects.

But I din't see any menu. Any helpful answer would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> adds selected objects to a new Group

Objects belonging to a group show up in green.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> removes active objects from a group.

If more than one object is selected and when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> but only one of them is removed from all groups, then afterwards press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> > *Groups* to remove all selected objects from all groups.

Answer (score 1):

If the green line appears only in Edit mode, just press Ctrl + E and "clear  sharp", or "Clear Freestyle Edge".